# How can we override getJobExplorer() when we create a SpringBatchConfig?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I've extended my SpringBatchConfig from BatchConfigurer, and everything went right but when it comes to getJobExplorer, it returns NullPointerException when calling it:

```
    @Override
    @Bean
    public JobExplorer getJobExplorer() throws Exception {
        return jobExplorer;
    }
```

Comment: You should create a `jobExplorer` just returning an uninitialized field will obviously lead to a null pointer.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like that and worked

```
public JobExplorer getJobExplorer() throws Exception {
        JobExplorerFactoryBean jobExplorerFactoryBean = new JobExplorerFactoryBean();
        jobExplorerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        jobExplorerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return jobExplorerFactoryBean.getObject();
    }
```